# How to deal with multiple xml standards?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am attempting to write a local set of wrapper classes into our institution API (I work at a post secondary institution). The purpose of these classes are to securely pull transcripts from a remote service, and to allow the abstraction away from how that service works to our programmers. How the service works is confidential however the question I need an answer too is this:

**How to deal with this when each transcript response comes in a different xml format depending on which of the schools it comes from. There are over 30.**

As an example: Institution A has the tag, at the top of the document near the root, for GPA of a student to be |GPA|4.0|/GPA| whereas another institution might have it in a completely different part of the XML, near the bottom and perhaps 3 children deep, and name the tag |GradePointAverage|4.0|/GradePointAverage|   (Pretend | is xml angle brackets)

Any suggestions how to deal with this lack of standardization?

Comment: the canonical answer is to use xslt to transform them all into a single standard format. In practice, however, I wouldn't want to be the one tasked with doing that; there are much easier ways to skin this cat than that.

Comment: Is it possible to create a standard template first and construct the standard xml template dynamicly. For example, for <name> element in the standard xml structure, you are going to search the value of <name> element in other xml documents and fill the template. Therefore you can construct a standard xml format from other formats. but you might be consider synonym as well

Comment: That would be nice, but there isn't even enough standardization to do that Larry, some append their institution names into it: |instA:GPA|4.0|/instA:GPA|

Comment: @Spudley Do you have any ideas for those other ways? I would like the cat to be very easily skinned.

Comment: How is this not a question? If it is closed as "Not a real question" then perhaps everyone has dealt with this problem so often that I'm just an idiot? if there is a simple solution, let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you should aim for one common data model, and then 30 different classes which are able to deserialize from XML to that data model. Depending on exactly how different they are, there *may* be significant aspects of reuse, and you may even be able to parameterize some differences. Using LINQ to XML makes it reasonably easy to parse any one format.

I would aim for lots of simple code rather than a small amount of "clever" code: parsing each individual format should be reasonably straightforward, and hopefully easy to test. Yes, it'll be tedious to write this code, but it should end up being easy to follow, and easy to add more formats if you need to.

You could use XSLT to perform a transformation into a single format of course, but personally I'd rather write C# :)

This assumes you *can* create a common data model - if the formats are very different, you may find that you can't accurately represent the data in each file without having a horrible lowest-common-denominator. Coming up with a good data model is likely to be as hard as writing each individual parser.

Comment: That is as I feared. I'd have 30 classes, or 1 class with 30 case statements filled with one liners of code to fill the main generic "Transcript" class object: TranscriptObject.Name = XMLGetValueLogicHere;  
TranscriptObject.GPA = XMLGetValueLogicHere;

Comment: @DFTR: Yes, you'll need 30 different bits of code. How else would you expect to deal with 30 different formats? This is why it's important that each piece of code is simple - it's boring to do, but it shouldn't cause long term problems. If one format changes a bit, it won't disturb anything else. If you no longer need a format, just get rid of it. If you need a new format, just add another class. Keep them as independent from each other as possible. It's tedious, but that's just the natural result of having to handle lots of different formats.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This is the solution I had thought of when I saw the awful mess of data. I was mostly just hoping I was incorrect. I'm going to leave this open for a while, if nobody has any other ideas, I'll mark yours correct.